# Storing average overall score calculated from one table in to another

Tags: sql

Easy I'm sure, but I'm still just getting started with SQL.
How do I store the average in to tblAccounts? This is what I have so far..

```
@playerAccountID uniqueidentifier,

UPDATE tblAccounts 
SET overallScore = ( 
   SELECT (  SUM(dart1)/COUNT(dart1) 
           + SUM(dart2)/COUNT(dart1)  
           + SUM(dart3)/COUNT(dart1) ) / 3
FROM tblScores
INNER JOIN tblAccounts.accountID 
   ON tblScores.accountID
WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID
) 
WHERE @playerAccountID = accountID
```

tblScores stores scores from each dart thrown. I require and average of all 3 darts thrown, so if dart1 = 40, dart2 = 60, dart3 = 20 Then the average would be 40. However there will be multiple rows in this table and what I require to be stored in tblAccounts is the average of all the averages.
EG:

```
30 40 20 = 30
40 40 40 = 40
15 15 15 = 45
```

The result I require from this example is (30+40+45)/3 as there's 3 rows but number of rows will vary.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of the logic you want, and a tag for the database you areusing.

Comment: I've updated the question. apologies.

Comment: `ON tblScores.accountID...` + `= tblAccounts.accountID` - this would be minimum required if your query was correct

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want arithmetic in a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tblAccounts
    SET overallScore = (SELECT (s.dart1 + s.dart2 + s.dart3) / 3
                        FROM tblScores s
                        WHERE s.playerAccountID = tblAccounts.playerAccountID                       
                       ) 
WHERE accountID = @playerAccountID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want to do:

```
UPDATE tblAccounts
SET overallScore = (AVG(s.dart1) + AVG(s.dart2) + AVG(s.dart3)) / 3
FROM tblScores s
INNER JOIN tblAccounts.accountID 
   ON tblScores.accountID = s.playerAccountID 
GROUP BY s.accountID   
HAVING s.playerAccountID = @playerAccountID;
```